# Regex Pattern For Finding String Before First Dot in Python

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex pattern to grab the string before the first dot:

```
 google.com.com
 yahoo.com
 192.168.1.4
```

I need a regex that gives google and yahoo, but my pattern grabs IP addresses too. My regex is `r'(.*)\.(.*)`

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: It's because the dot matches anything. If only there was a GREP code for "just letters"...

Comment: You need to define some rules by what logic are things valid - what if you had `999.com` for instance? What rules describe accurately what you want and what you dont'... letters only... anything followed by what looks like a TLD... etc... etc...

Comment: Try this: `^\w*[a-zA-Z]\w*`

Comment: When you say "string" do you mean that you don't want to return `192` (even though `192.168.1.4` is a string)?

Comment: @ctwheels there is only one match: https://regex101.com/r/fkgCEg/1

Comment: @Jasmin add the `m` flag: https://regex101.com/r/fkgCEg/2

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst yes

Comment: What do you **really** want to do? See [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the text you provided is one string with newlines. In that case, this would be a quick solution to pull the results into a list.

```
re.findall(r'^\s*([a-zA-Z]+)\.', str, re.MULTILINE)
```

The re.MULTILINE simplifies things by allowing the use of '^' to match the beginning of each line.

This results in `['google', 'yahoo']`.

For an explanation of the regex, see the verbose version below. (also good for documenting purposes)

```
re.findall(r'''
    ^           # beginning of each line (multiline mode)
    \s*         # zero or more whitespace characters
    ([a-zA-Z]+) # captures one or more characters a-z case-insensitive (just in case)
    \.          # matches '.'
    ''', str, re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure if the spaces on the beginning of the rows have any meaning, so I took them in account in [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/wTt7h2/2):

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))[\w-]+(?=.[a-zA-Z])
```

It matches substrings right after either the beginning of the row, or a space, that are followed by a dot and then **a letter** (as opposed to a digit).